# count multiple attributes sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i am looking for the following output

- 10 customers with 10 items bought in 2 product groups
- 8 customers with 10 items bought in 1 product group.

Generally a matrix with a customer count over items bought AND product groups, ie. counting over 2 attributes (items and product group)

I tried the code below, but then it only gives me

- 1 customer with 10 items and 2 product groups
- 1 customer with 10 items and 1 product group despite the fact that there is many more customers in each line:

snippet,

```
count (distinct customer_id) over (Partition by customer_id) as Customer_ID
,count (distinct customer_shipment_item_id) Over (Partition by customer_id) as customer_items
,count (distinct product_group) Over (Partition by customer_id) as customer_product_groups
```

Can you explain how this would work?

Comment: it would be easier if you provide schema and data example, with SQL Fiddle may be

Comment: Hi Roman, can i add a table here? The format breaks everytime i try do add some excel examples. thanks bianca

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Unless I don't understand what you are looking for, you don't need the Partition By clause.

```
count (distinct customer_id) as Customer_ID
,count (distinct customer_shipment_item_id) as customer_items
,count (distinct product_group) as customer_product_groups
```

Comment: Hi tom, thank you but this didnt work. It resulted in one line with x customers, y items, z product groups. i am looking for a matrix though, counted by customers: x customers with the combination of y1 products, z1 product groups, x customers with the combination of y2 products, z2 product groups and so on. Any ideas? Bianca

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would give you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT    COUNT(customer_id) Customer_ID, customer_items, customer_product_groups

FROM 

(SELECT   customer_id, COUNT(DISTINCT customer_shipment_item_id) as customer_items,
          COUNT(DISTINCT product_group) as customer_product_groups
 FROM     TABLENAME
          JOIN <YOUR JOINS>
 WHERE    customer_id IN (SELECT customer_ID FROM <YOUR JOINS> WHERE customer_shipment_item_id = x)
 GROUP BY customer_id
) a

GROUP BY customer_items, customer_product_groups
```

Comment: Hi Tom thank you, actually it works now but as this was only part of a question, the total result still doesnt work (my fault, just realized): The full question actually is, how do customers look like where the customer bought one or more items which fit in a certain criteria. Therefore i restricted the query to this criteria (customer_shipment_item_id =x). Now, i only get a part of the customer, i.e. the part where the criteria belongs to the item and not how does he/she look in total (where only one item might fit to the criteria). Does this make sense?

Comment: I just updated the code adding a WHERE clause to the subquery.  This will give you the exact same results for customer that have the customer_shipment_item_id you are looking for.